# PHPExcel import csv by batch in PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm having a problem in storing/importing huge CSV files with more than 1000 rows.
Only few rows are saved in the database, what came into my mind is to store/import the rows batch by batch but i don't know how to put it in my code:

My code:

```
require_once 'PHPexcel/PHPExcel.php';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
        $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
            $val=array();
            for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
                $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $val[] = $cell->getValue();

            }
        }
    }
```

My idea:

```
$counter = 0;
$total = 100;//get the total rows
while(true){
    $items = array();//get the first 20 rows from excel
    foreach($items as $item){
        //save in database

        if($counter == $total){
            break;
        } 
        $counter++;
    }

}
```